# Расположение файла в C++ под OS X

Tags: c++, macos, clion

Работаю в среде CLion от JetBrains под OS X.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream file("test1.txt");

    if (!file) {
        cout << "Файл не удалось открыть.\n";
        exit(-1);
    };

    file << "Работа с файлами в С++";
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Ожидается, что данный код после запуска создаст файл **test1.txt** и запишет в него строку, а если он создан, то просто откроет и изменит его. В результате ничего не происходит. Компилятор успешно открывает файл, записывает (вероятно) туда строку и завершает работу. Файл как был пустым (я его создал предварительно в директории, где лежит проект, а именно main.cpp и CMakeList.txt), так и остался. Что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

Comment: "*в директории, где лежит проект*" а надо бы в каталоге, где лежит собранный бинарь, наверное. В любом случае в начале `main()` выведите текущий каталог (см. `man getcwd` или что там под маком) -понятней станет.

Comment: BTW, ответ на вопрос " *Что я делаю не так?*" очень простой - не хотите осваивать азы: пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: Поищите в настройках CLion куда у него выставлена *Working directory* - именно там он будет создавать файл.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках сборки есть поле working directory в которой указанно в какой папки будет запускаться проект. По умолчанию он запускается во временных файлах c примерно таким путём `/projectName/_/2017/projectName/cmake-build-debug/`